# How add to route values elem with dot in key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I get the expected action on front this way:

```html
<a :href="'@Url.RouteUrl(ABC, new { id = (int?)null })/' +id+'?options.active=something'" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info"><i class="oi oi-eye"></i></a>
```

How to get the same in backend?
I tried: (also with serialization Options to json)

```cs
return RedirectToRoute(ABC, new { id, options = new Options(){ Active = "something" }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it this way:

```cs
System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            { "options.Active", "something" },
                            { "id", id }
                        };
                        return RedirectToRoute(ABC, routeValueDictionary);
```